# Shortcut to generate "Created by.." template in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have a project with a lot of classes in which I need to change the `Created by` template.

```
/**
 * Created by johnnyfivedev on 19.07.16.
 */
```

Since there are a lot of such classes, copy and paste not an option. Rather I want to remove that generated template and regenerate it. Is there any default shortcut for doing this? If not, then how do I create one?

Comment: check my edited answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Rather I want to remove that generated template and regenerate it.

You can surely edit the template but you can't regenerate it again. I suggest editing the template for your future uses and creating a live template for those made prior to this template change.

### Editing the template

Go to **Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates -> Includes -> File Header**

[image]

and override the `${USER}` function like so:

`#set( $USER = "Your name")`

[image]

If you want, you can add [a lot more variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html) to it.

**NOTE**: These changes will only take effect on *new* files. The ones made prior to this template change will have to be manually changed.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to go directly to the File and Code Templates tab.

### Creating the live template

Go to **Settings -> Editor -> Live Templates**

Press the green 'plus' sign to add a new template, and select `Live Template`.

[image]

In the `abbreviation` field, type what you want to, I typed `annot`, add a suitable description (optional) and insert the following code in the box:

```
/**
* Created by $USER$ on $DATE$.
*/

$END$
```

Select the `Edit variables` box and write the following expressions in the corresponding fields,

- `user()` for USER
- `date("dd-MM-yyyy")` for DATE

After that type define applicable contexts as you see fit. In your code, now type `annot` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the template.

In the code, your cursor will end up at the place of `$END$` upon pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after template insertion.

Comment: It doesn't answer my quesion. I want a SHORTCUT to recreate this template. Like, if you write "ifn" in java class and press enter it will create whole `if ( var !=null )` block. You wrote something, you pressed enter and template generated.

Comment: @Mr.Robot Now I understand what you want, I have edited your question giving greater clarity and have updated my answer. Hope it helps :)

Comment: It helped. I got what I wanted. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code generation template in settings of the android studio where you can change what name appears and date.

Here is a snapshot of where it is.

[image]

but this won't work for your existing files where you can change manually.